# How to reference "This" Column?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

Maybe I'm dumb, but how do you just reference "This" or "Current" column? For example, counting entries in a column.
I know you can enter a formula & drag it, or copy it & paste into a cell, but is is possible with something like a wildcard or arbitrary reference?

Obviously something like this works:

```
=COUNT(A:A)
```

But I'm really hoping for something more like this:

```
=COUNT("*":"*")
or
=COUNT(COLUMN("*"))
```

(Both always return a 0)

--

Perhaps it's not a formula, but a scripting solution. - Using Google Sheets, not Excel.

Comment: I think trying to count everything in "this" column would create a circular reference, as you'd be presumably entering the formula in the same column, and the formula would become one of the things that gets counted. Anyway, putting COLUMN() inside COUNT will just return 1, since COLUMN() returns a single integer representing the current column's position, and you would just be counting that integer.

Comment: True, I can see how it could result in a circular reference. Hoping there may have been a simple solution, because it seems like there _should_ be one. Using `=Column()` is kind of self-referencing, by returning the cell's position; was hoping I could use it to reference the entire column.

Comment: `=Column()` is not self referencing, it is a properties extractor.. like `CELL()`. | Putting 'SUM(A1:A3)` in cell `A1` is self referencing.. Coz we do : `A1 = A1 + A2 + A3` ... is mathematically impossible (circular reference). | Any example of operation with "wildcard or arbitrary reference"  you are need to do/test ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Exclude one cell

If you formula is in the first row you can simply exclude it.

**Example**
Formula in A1 to count the entire row excluding A1:
 `=COUNT(A2:A)`

If you start you data further down, say in the 10th row:
`=COUNT(A10:A)`